# Attribute is not defined in Gatling

Tags: scala, scala-gatling

I have this simulation file.
My idea is created a json file, in the json file has some parameter.
The parameters will be passed value by feeder in gatling.
But the problem is when I do that, parameter is not passed value.

```
package tci3accountPro

import baseConfig.BaseSimulation
import io.gatling.core.Predef._
import io.gatling.http.Predef._
import tci3accountPro.models.bodyRegisterSubs
import core.api.ApiUtil

import scala.concurrent.duration._

class registerSubscriptions extends BaseSimulation{

  val username = "105C169260"

  val cashAccount = "11111"

  val proCode = "IWEALTH_PRO"
  val typeText = "TRIAL"
  val referrerId105C = "105C310885"

  var ini = new GetTokenApi

  val token = ini.getToken(username)

  val registerSubs = http.baseUrl(accountProDomain + accountProSubs)
    .header("Authorization", token)
    .header("Content-Type","application/json")


  var feeder =  Iterator.continually(Map(
    "cashAccount" -> cashAccount,
    "code105C" -> username,
    "proCode" -> proCode,
    "type" -> typeText,
    "referrerId105C" -> referrerId105C
  ))

  def registerSub() = {
    feed(feeder)
    exec(http("register Subscriptions")
      .post("")
      .body(ElFileBody("bodies/bodyRegisterSubs.json")).asJson
      .check(status.is(200)))
  }

  val scn = scenario("register Subscriptions")
    .exec(registerSub)

  setUp(scn.inject(atOnceUsers(1),rampUsersPerSec(1) to 5 during (10 seconds)).protocols(registerSubs)).maxDuration(1 minutes)
    .assertions(global.responseTime.max.lt(2000), global.successfulRequests.percent.gt(95))
}
```

and the json file

```
{
  "cashAccount": "${cashAccount}",
"code105C": "${code105C}",
"proCode": "${proCode}",
"type": "${type}",
"referrerId105C": "${referrerId105C}"
}
```

But when run the simulation, it shows : no attribute name "cashAccount" is defined.
Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

in your registerSub definition you need to chain your methods - as written, it's just returning the exec as that is the last statement.

change it to...

```
def registerSub() = {
feed(feeder)
.exec(http("register Subscriptions")
  .post("")
  .body(ElFileBody("bodies/bodyRegisterSubs.json")).asJson
  .check(status.is(200)))
```

}